# MacOS: How to turn off Option key printing special characters in VS Code, IntelliJ etc

Tags: macos, keyboard, visual-studio-code

Most code editors like IntelliJ, VSCode etc have many shortcuts using the 'option' key in mac. For me, using the option key would cause a special character to be printed instead of performing the shortcut. I wanted to turn this feature off.

I managed to do it after some googling. To serve as a documentation, I am answering my own question below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most code editors like IntelliJ, VSCode etc have many shortcuts using the 'option' key in mac. For me, using the option key would cause a special character to be printed instead of performing the shortcut.

How to fix this:

Go to system preferences > keyboard.

My Keyboard was set to 'ABC - extended'. Which had special characters turning up on pressing the 'option' key. I Changed the keyboard to 'ABC' , ie, one without the extension part.

Problem solved.

Why? Coz the 'ABC' keyboard doesnt have the special characters in them :)

Comment: `ABC` doesn't seem to work for me on MacOS 12. Still has the special characters.

Answer (score 4):

[This answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16019737/830254) how to completely prevent Option+key from producing special characters, allowing you to use these combinations for shortcuts in VS Code and various other editors.

In short:

1. [Download this QWERTY keyboard layout file](https://gist.github.com/greneholt/e7d5373f96cc0f815717c7666790324d) (or generate one yourself using the instructions in the linked answer).
2. Move it to `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`
3. Go to `System Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Text Input` > `Input Sources` > `Edit`.
4. Click `+` in the bottom left, scroll to the bottom of the list on the left and select `Others` then select `QWERTY no option` and click `Add`.
5. Either delete your existing layout (probably called `U.S.`) or just switch to the `QWERTY no option` layout using the input-source select in the menu bar.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I am no longer using mac, so cannot confirm if this helps of not, but given the upvotes, seems correct :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Sonoma 14.2.1

- Navigate to **System Settings** -> **Keyboard**
- Under the **Text Input** section, click on the **Edit** button for **Input Sources**. A window will pop up to allow you to manage your input sources.
- Click on the **+** button on the bottom-left corner, and a new popup will appear to ask you to choose a language.
- Under **Others** (bottom of the list for me), there should be an option for **Unicode Hex Input**. This QWERTY layout has nothing mapped to the Option layer.
- (Optional) I then removed my usual ABC keybaord.

[image]

*Edit* - I just noticed that Opt+ and Opt+ to move between words doesn't seem to work robustly. It behaves well in most text editing scenarios, but not in the URL bar for Google Chrome.